# jquery.nav.js is not working after one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> Getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined(…) jquery.nav.js:183`

I'm trying to transform my web app to SPA using  jquery.nav.js (see https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav). Here is my code:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav').onePageNav({});
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" style="background-color:white">
      <ol class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-right">
        <li>        
        <a href="#section-home" class="current">
        <span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs current">        
        <a href="#section-services">
        <span >Services</span></a></li>

       </ol>
</div>
```

After clicking on services, it goes to right place but it can't go back to home if I click on Home. Any idea why it's not going back to home?

Comment: Does the error show just as you click Services, or when you click Home?  If it is when Home, I would suspect that section-home is not defined (like section-services) correctly.

Comment: @rfornal, Thanks man. Such a silly mistake!

Comment: I'm going to post as an answer so that you can mark it correct and this question closed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the error show just as you click Services, or when you click Home? If it is when Home, I would suspect that section-home is not defined (like section-services) correctly.